# Getting routes.rb root to work in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubymine

Started working with RoR again! I'm having trouble getting my config/routes.rb file to perform. I'm getting "uninitialized constant ApplicationsController" using RubyMine.

Here's what I have changed in my routes.rb after trying to search things down:

```
resources :applications  
root :to => 'applications#index'

application_controller.rb has:
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
end
```

I've ran my rake routes:

```
    applications GET    /applications(.:format)          applications#index
                 POST   /applications(.:format)          applications#create
 new_application GET    /applications/new(.:format)      applications#new
edit_application GET    /applications/:id/edit(.:format) applications#edit
     application GET    /applications/:id(.:format)      applications#show
                 PUT    /applications/:id(.:format)      applications#update
                 DELETE /applications/:id(.:format)      applications#destroy
            root        /                                applications#index
```

`rake rails:update` and all changes were approved except altering routes.rb
Heres what its kicks out Rubymine side:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-11 02:50:27 -0800
Connecting to database specified by database.yml

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant ApplicationsController):
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have a file called `applications_controller` in your `app/controller` folder, or its name is `application_controller`, so rename it to `applications_controller`, if you don't have that file, then create your `ApplicationsController`:

`rails generate controller applications`

Comment: Ended up having to generate a brand new controller called applications_controller.rb. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should rename `application_controller.rb` to `applications_controller.rb`

Comment: Hmmm plurality issue with the naming of a file? or Generating issue?

Comment: @Matt In rails this is know as *convention over configuration*. By default all controllers must be pluralized. Model: User Controller: UsersController